# wordpress url correction

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, site-url, routing

I have my wordpress site in a root folder like this "www.mysite/myblog/"

so to get to the blog you have to go to "www.mysite/myblog/"

I'm wanting to make it so that a user can go to "www.mysite" and it hits the blog. What do I need to do. All my images and everything have the ".../myblog/" path. I don't want to have to go through and correct all this because I'm sure that I'll mess something up.

so basically wanting some help on how to do this.

any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the index.php and .htaccess file(Just copy it , do not move it ) from myblog directory to root directory.

Open index.php file in any text editor and find the following code in the file.

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Replace it with the following code and save the file.

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./myblog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Go to the General Settings page from settings section in the back end and change Site Address (URL) field to http://wwww.mysite.com as shown below in screenshot.

[image: General Settings]

You can get more information on this settings from [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install).

You can access backend of site from this URL : http://www.mysite.com/myblog/wp-admin

If you face any problem then let me know..

Comment: This page in Codex outlines the process: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory: Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install). You will have to change the site URL in settings as well for this to work.

Comment: will I need to do anything with the image url's ?

Comment: @user987795 No you do not need to do anything with the image url's.

Answer (score 1):

I case of an Apache HTTP server you can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /myblog/ [QSA,L]
```

This will take care of the home page.